# if login is true redirect to dashboard in php not working

Tags: php, authentication, session

i have created a login in php , when user logs in it will redirect to dashboard. if the user is already logged in and tries to access login page, it should redirect him to dashboard

i have tried something like below code:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
session_start();

include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['entering']))
  {
    $adminuser = $_POST['password'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select id from users where  password='$adminuser'");

    $ret=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if($ret>0 ){
      $_SESSION['cvmsaid']=$ret['ID'];
     header('location:dashboard.php');
    }
    else{
    $msg="Invalid Password.";
    }
  }

if($_SESSION['cvmsaid']){
   header("location:dashboard.php");
   exit();
}
```

such that when the user tries to view login page after logging in, it should redirect him to dashboard, but this code is not working. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Tried adding `isset()` to your if condition?

Comment: Show where the session variable was initially set

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi i tried like this if(isset($_SESSION['login'])), not working

Comment: Try doing a `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: @a Array ( [cvmsaid] => ) its showing this

Comment: from you print there isn't property called `login` in your `$_SESSION` the problem here is from your login page

Comment: @Joseph actually i am using cvmsaid instead of 'login', in the question i added 'login'

Comment: Add Login Code!

Comment: How you can see you didin't do any session login variable.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini i didnt understand what you said

Comment: Add before `$_SESSION['cvmsaid']=$ret['ID'];` - `$_SESSION['LOGIN']=TRUE;`, now in all age you can do `if($_SESSION['LOGIN']==TRUE) do...`

Comment: Try with isset() ```if(isset($_SESSION['cvmsaid'])){
   header("Location: dashboard.php");
   exit();
}```

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat You are welcome ;), acept my answer with 1 upvote please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Active session variable:

```
if($ret>0 ){
      $_SESSION['cvmsaid']=$ret['ID'];
      $_SESSION['login']=TRUE;
     header('location:dashboard.php');
    }
```

Use it in all page:

```
if( $_SESSION['login']==FALSE){
header('location:login.php');
}
```